# Question regarding measurement induced phase transitions

Tags: quantum-information, phase-transition, quantum-measurements

It is often claimed in the literature of random quantum hybrid circuits that a measurement induced phase transition is invisible in trajectory averages of linear observables and can only be seen in trajectory averages of non-linear observables (see [here](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-conmatphys-031720-030658), [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-03998-0_9) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.02986)). Romain Vasseur in his BSS lectures (see [here](https://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Boulder%20Summer%20School.pdf)), makes the following argument to justify this claim:

> Let's consider a brick-wall circuit in which we have the following pattern of evolution: first we apply a Haar random unitary upon even links, then a few measurements are randomly made followed by Haar random unitaries applied to the odd links. The trajectory average i.e. average over different measurement outcomes can be written as a quantum channel:
> $$\bar{\rho}_t = \sum_{\{m\}} |\psi_{m} \rangle \langle \psi_{m} | = N_t(\rho)=\sum_{\{m\}} K_m \rho K_m^{\dagger}$$
> where the Kraus operators are of the form:
> $$K_m  = \prod_{\tau=1}^t \hat{\Pi}^{m_T^{'}} U_\tau^{\text {odd }} \hat{\Pi}^{m_T} U_\tau^{\text {even }}$$
> here,
>
> - $\hat{\Pi}^{m_T^{'}}$: the projector onto measurement outcome $m_T^{'}$
> - $U_\tau^{\text {odd }}$: Haar-random unitary acting on odd links
> - $U_\tau^{\text {even }}$: Haar-random unitary acting on even links
>
> The central claim is that linear quantities such as $\langle O \rangle$,
> $$\langle O \rangle = \sum_{\{m\}} p_m \frac{\left\langle\psi_m|O| \psi_m\right\rangle}{\left\langle\psi_n \mid \psi_n\right\rangle}=\text{Tr}{\left(\bar{\rho}*t O\right)}$$
> cannot "see" measurement induced phase transitions as at long times, the trajectory averaged density matrix becomes an infinite temperature state:
> $$\rho_t \rightarrow \rho_{\infty}=\frac{1}{d^L} \mathbb{I}$$
> This can be shown by taking the following limit:
> $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \bar{\rho}_t = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{\{m\}} K_m \rho K_m^{\dagger}$$

My questions are the following:

1. How does one compute this limit?
2. How does one generalize this argument beyond brick-wall circuits? Is there rather a more intuitive way to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the Kraus operators $K_m$, trajectory average is given by the channel defined by the equation,
$$ \bar{\rho}_t = \sum_{\{m\}} \prod_{\tau = 1}^{t} \left(\hat{\Pi}^{m_T^{'}} U_\tau^{\text{odd }} \hat{\Pi}^{m_T} U_\tau^{\text{even }}\right) \rho \left(  U_\tau^{\dagger \text{ even }} \hat{\Pi}^{m_T} U_\tau^{\dagger \text{ odd }} \hat{\Pi}^{m_T^{'}} \right).$$

Now to evaluate the limit for $t \to \infty$, we must consider the Haar averages as the specifics of the random unitaries essentially wash out at this limit, leaving only the averaged effect. Given a Haar-random unitary $U$, the expectation value of the linear operator $U \mathcal{O} U^\dagger$ with respect to the Haar-measure is given by (see [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/show-that-averaging-over-uniformly-random-unitaries-mathbbeuxu-dagger?noredirect=1&lq=1)),
$$ \mathbb{E}_U (U \mathcal{O} U^\dagger) \equiv \int_{\mathbf U(d)} d\mu(U) U \mathcal{O} U^\dagger = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal{O})\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}. $$

Using the above expression we compute Haar averages over even and odd links to get,
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \bar{\rho}_t = \lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{\{m\}} \prod_{\tau = 1}^{t} \frac{\mathbb{I}}{d} \hat{\Pi}^{m_T^{'}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{I}}{d^t} = \frac{\mathbb{I}}{d^L} $$

As you can see from the above expression, with increasing $t$, the state gets increasingly mixed. At $t \to \infty$, we can physically intuit that this must converge to the maximally mixed state.

I believe this answer should give some intuition to the result, as well as possible extensions therof, as it has been derived mostly using physical principles.